# Calling parent view from child fragment - view pager

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewpager, fragment

I have a fragment with a searchBox and underneath that viewpager is placed ,
I get access to the searchBox from child like this :
`(this.parentFragment as TicketListFragment).binding.searchBpx.setOnTextChange {}`

in each child fragment everthing works fine , the problem is here:
Fragemnt A: `(this.parentFragment as TicketListFragment).binding.searchBpx.setOnTextChange { Log.d("accessing to the searchBox from frag a")`
}

Fragemnt B: `(this.parentFragment as TicketListFragment).binding.searchBpx.setOnTextChange { Log.d("accessing to the searchBox from frag B")`
}

when i go to frag B  , and get back to the frag A , the `searchBox.setOnTextChange` is called from frag B !!,
any idea to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing the parent search view from its children FragmentA and FragmentB. And you set the `setOnTextChange` on both the fragment.

So before going to another fragment you should remove the listener from the current fragment.

For Example :
going From A -> B: Remove the `setOnTextChange` from Fragment A then proceed to B.

Comment: how to remove it? cause onDestroy method on fragments doesn't get called

Comment: you can use onPause